# Excepción de HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8 en DPFP.Verification U ARE U 4500

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2014

Estoy trabajando un reloj checador, sin embargo al realizar la verificación, me tira el error:

> Excepción de HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8 en DPFP.Verification U ARE U 4500

He consultado esta misma pregunta en varios foros pero ninguna de las modificaciones propuestas me ha solucionado el problema, comienzo proporcionando esta información, por si fuera de utilidad:

Estoy trabajando en Visual studio 2017, windows Form y sistema operativo windows 10 de 64 bits.

Base de datos SQL Server 2014

Tabla `UsuarioHuella`

```
Id - int
UsuarioId - int
Sample1 - varbinary(MAX)
Sample2 - varbinary(MAX)
Sample3 - varbinary(MAX)
```

Aquí el código:

```
public void OnComplete(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, DPFP.Sample Sample)
    {

        DPFP.FeatureSet Caracteristicas = new DPFP.FeatureSet();
        Caracteristicas = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification);

        if (Caracteristicas != null)
        {
            Verification Verificador = new Verification();
            bool Valido = false;

            AlbatrosCtx ctx = new AlbatrosCtx();
            var ListaHuellas = (from huella in ctx.UsuarioHuellaDB
                                join Usr in ctx.UsuarioDB
                                on huella.UsuarioId equals Usr.Id
                                join Area in ctx.TipoAreaDB
                                on Usr.TipoAreaId equals Area.Id
                                let AreaNombre = Area.Nombre
                                where Usr.Status == (byte)Usuario.EStatus.Activo
                                select new
                                {
                                    Usr.Id,
                                    Usr.Nombre,
                                    Usr.Apellidos,
                                    AreaNombre,
                                    huella.Sample1,
                                    huella.Sample2,
                                    huella.Sample3
                                }).ToList();

            foreach (var Registro in ListaHuellas)
            {
                DPFP.Template Modelo = new DPFP.Template();
                Modelo.DeSerialize(Registro.Sample1);

                DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result resultado = new DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result();
                Verificador.Verify(Caracteristicas, Modelo, ref resultado);

                if(resultado.Verified)
                {
                    Valido = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Modelo.DeSerialize(Registro.Sample2);
                    Verificador.Verify(Caracteristicas, Modelo, ref resultado);

                    if(resultado.Verified)
                    {
                        Valido = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Modelo.DeSerialize(Registro.Sample3);
                        Verificador.Verify(Caracteristicas, Modelo, ref resultado);

                        if (resultado.Verified)
                        {
                            Valido = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(Valido == true)
                {
                    LblId.Text = "ID: " + Registro.Id.ToString();
                    LblNombre.Text = "Nombre: " + Registro.Nombre + " " + Registro.Apellidos;
                    LblArea.Text = Registro.AreaNombre;

                    break;
                }

            }


            if(Valido == true)
            {
                LecturaCorrecta();
            }
            else
            {
                LecturaErronea();
            }                

            TmrRegistro.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            LecturaErronea();
        }


    }

protected DPFP.FeatureSet ExtractFeatures(DPFP.Sample Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose Purpose)
    {
        DPFP.Processing.FeatureExtraction Extractor = new DPFP.Processing.FeatureExtraction();  // Create a feature extractor
        DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback feedback = DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.None;
        DPFP.FeatureSet features = new DPFP.FeatureSet();
        Extractor.CreateFeatureSet(Sample, Purpose, ref feedback, ref features);            // TODO: return features as a result?
        if (feedback == DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.Good)
            return features;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Justo al llegar a la linea `Verificador.Verify(Caracteristicas, Modelo, ref resultado);` el programa se detiene y marca el siguiente error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Excepción de HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8'

Comment: No sabemos que objeto es `Verification`. Deberías [edit] la pregunta y añadirlo, ya que puede ser una información importante.

Comment: DPFP.Verification forma parte de las clases del SDK del Dispositivo, no lo he añadido, porque es código al que ya no tengo acceso, simplemente instanciar las clases y llamar a sus métodos